# Django-admin как изменить внешний вид?

Tags: python, django-admin, django

На хостинг (бегет) поставил `django suit`. Надеялся, что в итоге админка будет выглядеть, как в примерах у django suit. Однако вид админки по-прежнему таков, как будто используется встроенная админка джанго, хотя на входе в админку видно, что suit подключен. Такое ощущение, что подключено все, кроме CSS.

Сколько не рылся в инете, так и не нашел способа привести админку к "приятному" виду. Может, кто сталкивался с похожей проблемой? Как решали?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$ln -s da/staticF static` вот эдакая команда решила проблему. Техподдержка на хостинге сообразила, что нужно сделать. Насколько я понял, нужно было создать ссылку на каталог со статическими файлами (CSS, js и пр). 'static' - значение переменной `STATIC_URL` файла `settings.py`.

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я знаю для подключения этой темы для админки ничего менять в статике не надо - встроенный сервер ищет статику по путям, указанным в настройках, а на продакшене этим рулит веб-сервер, а для сбора статики используется команда `collectstatic`. Возможно вы упустили какие-то шаги из [инструкции по установке](https://django-suit.readthedocs.org/en/develop/#installation)? Или неправильно настроили STATIC_ROOT.